# Delete a specific row in numpy array after applying a condition

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, row, element

I have an array that its name is packets, and has 9 columns and thousands of rows. I need to delete the rows based on the following condition: If each of element in column 1 is zero then delete related row.

This is the code:

```
for k in range(packets.shape[0]):
    np.delete(packets, np.where(packets[k, 0] == 1), axis = 0)
```

but it does not delete related row.
I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: `packets = packets[packets[:, 0] != 1]`?

Comment: Your description and code are not consistent. Can you provide an example input and expected output?

Comment: Thanks, (packets = packets[packets[:, 0] != 1]) works correctly.